# iOS - Get location of a view in a window?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwindow

I have a UIView that displays a popup after it's been clicked.
The popup needs to be added to the main UIWindow to make sure that it goes on top of everything else.

I want the position of this popup to be relative to my UIView, so I need to know the relative location of my UIView in the window.

Question: How can I find the location of a UIView in a UIWindow when the UIView is not directly in the UIWindow (It's inside the view of my viewController)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use can use the UIView method covertRect:toView to convert to the new co-ordinate space.  I did something very similar:

```
// Convert the co-ordinates of the view into the window co-ordinate space
CGRect newFrame = [self convertRect:self.bounds toView:nil];

// Add this view to the main window
[self.window addSubview:self];
self.frame = newFrame;
```

In my example, self is a view that is being removed from its superView and added to the window over the top of where it was.  The nil parameter in the toView: means use the window rather than a specific view.

Hope this helps,

Dave

Comment: Perfect.  There are several of these types of method for converting to and from co-ordinate spaces if you need them.

Comment: Does this work when the view is inside an UIScrollView

Comment: @AntiMoron, does it? Given the time that has passed, or are you supposed to traverse through converting from one frame to another and then the window?

Comment: It should work, also see the nil parameter means use the window rather than a specific view, so no need to traverse.

Comment: Shouldn't the convertRect method be passed self.frame, instead of self.bounds?  Why would you want to convert the rect of your bounds, which (nearly) always has origin 0,0?

Comment: The origin of the frame is relative to the superview.  The convertRect method is coverting the coordinates from your view's co-ordinate system to the supplied view's one.  In this case we want the whole view's rectangle in the window, hence we want (0,0) - (width, height).  Other times we might want to find the co-ordinates of a rect within the view (like the bounding box of a touch),  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

You can ask your `.superview` to convert your `origin` for you for you

```
CGPoint originGlobal = [myView.superview convertPoint:myView.frame.origin 
                                               toView:nil];
```

Answer (score 8):

Does UIView's convertPoint:toView: not work? So:

```
CGPoint windowPoint = [myView convertPoint:myView.bounds.origin toView:myWindow];
```

Answer (score 7):

I needed to do this in **Xamarin.iOS**

For anyone looking for a solution there, what eventually worked for me was:

```
CGRect globalRect = smallView.ConvertRectToView(smallView.Bounds, rootView);
```

Comment: this was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5 utility**

```
extension UIView {
    var originOnWindow: CGPoint { return convert(CGPoint.zero, to: nil) }
}
```

Usage

```
let positionOnWindow = view.originOnWindow
```

For **UIScrollView** it is slightly different

```
extension UIScrollView {
    var originOnWindow: CGPoint { return convert(contentOffset, to: nil) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Xamarin.iOS Implementation Worked For Me.

```
    CGRect GetRectAsPerWindow(UIView view)
    {
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        return view.Superview.ConvertRectToView(view.Frame, window);
    }
```

Pass in the view whose frame you want with respect to Window.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
extension UIView {
    var globalFrame: CGRect {
        return convert(bounds, to: window)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -8):

```
CGRect myFrame = self.superview.bounds;
```

Comment: ader I would delete this answer if I were you. Lots of down votes..