# Getting the coordinate of a UIImage which is a subview of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView. And for each UITableViewCell I have subviews such as UIImage and UILabel.

Now I want to find the exact coordinate (Preferably the CGRect) of one of the UIImages when I only have the reference to it.

One way I can think of is somehow get the coordinate of the parent UITableViewCell; Get the location of the UIImage **within** the cell, and then add them up.

But I am not sure if this is the best way. Isn't there an easy way to just take any UIView type and get its coordinate within the entire view, even if it's a subview of a UITableViewCell?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028850/ios-get-location-of-a-view-in-a-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIView` has a set of instance methods that let you convert frames and points from one coordinate system to another. [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert)

This could work in your parent View controller:

```
let convertedRect = cell.convert(cell.myImageView.frame, to: self.view)
```