# How to get subview's frame in the windows' reference (objc)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've already found some kind of solution to the question I answered but it doesn't fix the problem I have:

(where I searched : [Get position of UIView in respect to its superview's superview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572304/get-position-of-uiview-in-respect-to-its-superviews-superview),

[How to get the frame of a view inside another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082493/how-to-get-the-frame-of-a-view-inside-another-view),

[iOS - Get location of a view in a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028850/ios-get-location-of-a-view-in-a-window) ...and more)

I wrote that code:

```
CGRect targetFrame = [self.view convertRect:self.buttonImageView.frame
                                           fromView:self.view];
CGRect superView1Frame = [self.view convertRect:self.buttonImageView.superview.frame
                                           fromView:self.view];
CGRect superView2Frame = [self.view convertRect:self.buttonImageView.superview.superview.frame
                                           fromView:self.view];
        
targetFrame.origin.y = targetFrame.origin.y + superView1Frame.origin.y + superView2Frame.origin.y;
targetFrame.origin.x = targetFrame.origin.x + superView1Frame.origin.x + superView2Frame.origin.x;
```

which works well and I can get the target frame I want.

But, the fact is that code is very ugly and I'm sure there is another way to do it. I've already tried that kind of things :

```
CGRect targetFrame = [self.wallButtonImage.superview.superview convertRect:self.wallButtonImage.frame
                                                                          fromView:self.buttonImageView.superview.superview];
return [self.wallButtonImage.superview.superview convertRect:targetFrame
                                                            fromView:self.buttonImageView.superview.superview];
```

But it doesn't work at all...

Question(s) : Is there a way to get the same result as I did have in my first example but using another method? Or is there simply better way to do it?

Also, I can't understand why I can't find any other solution for it, so can you please explain me what you would have done?

Comment: Can you try this `CGRect frame = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];`?

Comment: Did not work but I found the solution so I'll post it, thanks for your help, you pushed me on the right way to find it :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good fact is that I found the solution :

```
CGRect targetFrame = [self.view convertRect:self.projectTitle.bounds fromView:self.projectTitle];
```

I'll explain a bit for people who didn't understand like me :

- `[self.view` is the view you want to get the frame's coordinates in.
- `convertRect:self.projectTitle.bounds` this is for the bounds of the view you want to get the frame's coordinates.
- `fromView:self.projectTitle];` is finally the view you want to get the frame's coordinates.
- so `targerFrame` is the frame of your initial view in the window's coordinates reference.

I did missunderstodd the third param, that is the reason why I was wrong !